# Dynamic React Form with dynamic fields

Tags: reactjs, redux-toolkit

I have design screen that is a form where you can add or delete fields as you wish.

[image]

Every time that you click a button you are create a component (text, image, title...).

Under the hood every component create this object:

```
{
              "title_item_lateral": "",
              "text_item_lateral": [],
              "image_lateral": [
                {
                  "title_image_lateral": "",
                  "path_image_lateral": ""
                }
              ],
              "document_lateral": [],
              "links": [
                {
                  "title_link": "",
                  "link": ""
                }
              ]
 }
```

How can i start to create this? i know how create a dynamic form, but always show in screen all the fields, but showing only one different field for every button, i don't know.

I am a bit loose now.
Thanks for your light in my way.

Comment: Know i think that maybe is better create an slice 'allItems.slice', with an array empty, and push a new object with all the properties, everytime that i click one of the buttons in the form.